# how to map an array of items to a new array in lowercase Javascript

Tags: javascript

Trying to map the animal_names to a new array and lowercase them.

```
const zooAnimals = [
  { animal_name: "Jackal, asiatic", population: 5, scientific_name: "Canis aureus", state: "Kentucky" },
  { animal_name: "Screamer, southern", population: 1, scientific_name: "Chauna torquata", state: "Alabama" },
  { animal_name: "White spoonbill", population: 8, scientific_name: "Platalea leucordia", state: "Georgia" },
];

const lowCaseAnimalNames = [];

zooAnimals.map(function(arrItem){
  lowCaseAnimalNames = arrItem.animal_name.toLowerCase
});

console.log(lowCaseAnimalNames);
```

Comment: `.toLowerCase()` - It's a function, you need `()` to invoke it

Comment: Use `return arrItem.animal_name.toLowerCase();` and set `lowCaseAnimalNames` equal to the return of running `.map()` instead of an empty array

Answer (score 2):

[`toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) is a method, to call or invoke that you have to specify `()` after the method name.

Also since [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) ***creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array***, you can simply ***return*** the modified item.

```js
const zooAnimals = [
  { animal_name: "Jackal, asiatic", population: 5, scientific_name: "Canis aureus", state: "Kentucky" },
  { animal_name: "Screamer, southern", population: 1, scientific_name: "Chauna torquata", state: "Alabama" },
  { animal_name: "White spoonbill", population: 8, scientific_name: "Platalea leucordia", state: "Georgia" },
];

const lowCaseAnimalNames = zooAnimals.map(function(arrItem){
  return arrItem.animal_name.toLowerCase();
});

console.log(lowCaseAnimalNames);
```

Answer (score 1):

[`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) will build a new Array with the *returned* value, so you should assign it directly to `lowCaseAnimalNames`

[`.toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) is a function, so needs `()` to invoke it

With your original map, you would also have issue with `lowCaseAnimalNames = arrItem.animal_name.toLowerCase()` - As this would be trying to overwrite a [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) variable which isn't allowed

```js
const zooAnimals = [
  { animal_name: "Jackal, asiatic", population: 5, scientific_name: "Canis aureus", state: "Kentucky" },
  { animal_name: "Screamer, southern", population: 1, scientific_name: "Chauna torquata", state: "Alabama" },
  { animal_name: "White spoonbill", population: 8, scientific_name: "Platalea leucordia", state: "Georgia" },
];

const lowCaseAnimalNames = zooAnimals.map(function(arrItem) {
  return arrItem.animal_name.toLowerCase();
});

console.log(lowCaseAnimalNames);
```

Answer (score 0):

`array.map()` method will create a new array of elements based on the given function and return the new array for you.

```
  const zooAnimals = [
        { animal_name: "Jackal, asiatic", population: 5, scientific_name: "Canis aureus", state: "Kentucky" },
        { animal_name: "Screamer, southern", population: 1, scientific_name: "Chauna torquata", state: "Alabama" },
        { animal_name: "White spoonbill", population: 8, scientific_name: "Platalea leucordia", state: "Georgia" },
      ];

    let lowCaseAnimalNames = zooAnimals.map((arrItem) => arrItem.animal_name.toLowerCase());
    console.log(lowCaseAnimalNames);
```